# How make color text in conky with out_to_console mode?

Tags: lua, archlinux, conky

Want to use conky against i3status in i3wm, but can't change color of the text, ${color 20B00B} not help, so how change font color? + also want beautiful graphics of cpu work, but in console mode i gets something like this ##____ 
[image]

```
    use_xft yes
    xftfont Terminus Regular:size=8
    out_to_console yes
    out_to_x no
    double_buffer yes
    update_interval 1.0
    cpu_avg_samples 8
    TEXT
    [
    { "full_text" : " A: ${moc_album} Artist: ${moc_artist} Song:{moc_song} || ♬ : ${exec ~/bin/volume} " , "color" : "\#6599F6"},
    { "full_text" : "Total Down: ${totaldown eth0} "  },
    { "full_text" : "Total Up: ${totalup eth0} " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
    { "full_text" : "GPU Temp: ${exec nvidia-smi -q -d TEMPERATURE | grep 'GPU Current Temp' | cut -c39-40}°C " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
    { "full_text" : "CPU: $cpu% " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
    { "full_text" : "RAM: $mem/$memmax " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
    { "full_text" : " ${time %a %d/%b %R}"},
    { "full_text" : " ${exec skb 1}" , "color" : "\#42BC24" }
    ]
```

There is one idea that this is problem creates i3.conf, so this my conf:

```
    # This file has been auto-generated by i3-config-wizard(1).
    # It will not be overwritten, so edit it as you like.
    #
    # Should you change your keyboard layout some time, delete
    # this file and re-run i3-config-wizard(1).
    #

    # i3 config file (v4)
    #
    # Please see http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!

    set $mod Mod4

    # Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
    # is used in the bar {} block below.
    font pango:Tamsyn 8 

    # This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
    # text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
    #font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 8

    # Before i3 v4.8, we used to recommend this one as the default:
    # font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
    # The font above is very space-efficient, that is, it looks good, sharp and
    # clear in small sizes. However, its unicode glyph coverage is limited, the old
    # X core fonts rendering does not support right-to-left and this being a bitmap
    # font, it doesn’t scale on retina/hidpi displays.

    # Use Mouse+$mod to drag floating windows to their wanted position
    floating_modifier $mod

    # Volume control
    bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q set Master 3%+
    bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q set Master 3%-
    bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q set Master toggle
    bindsym $mod+Escape exec /home/gyok/.config/scripts/i3lockMod.sh
    bindsym Print exec /home/gyok/.config/scripts/screenshot.sh
    bindsym Ctrl+Print exec /home/gyok/.config/scripts/screenshotCut.sh
    bindsym $mod+Shift+f exec chromium


    # start a terminal
    bindsym $mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal

    # kill focused window
    bindsym $mod+Shift+q kill

    # start dmenu (a program launcher)
    bindsym $mod+d exec dmenu_run
    # There also is the (new) i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications
    # shipping a .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that
    # installed.
    # bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

    # change focus
    bindsym $mod+h focus left
    bindsym $mod+j focus down
    bindsym $mod+k focus up
    bindsym $mod+l focus right

    # alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
    #bindsym $mod+Left focus left
    #bindsym $mod+Down focus down
    #bindsym $mod+Up focus up
    #bindsym $mod+Right focus right

    # move focused window
    bindsym $mod+Shift+h move left
    bindsym $mod+Shift+j move down
    bindsym $mod+Shift+k move up
    bindsym $mod+Shift+l move right

    # alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
    #bindsym $mod+Shift+Left move left
    #bindsym $mod+Shift+Down move down
    #bindsym $mod+Shift+Up move up
    #bindsym $mod+Shift+Right move right

    # split in horizontal orientation
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+h split h

    # split in vertical orientation
    bindsym $mod+Ctrl+v split v

    # enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
    bindsym $mod+f fullscreen toggle

    # change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
    bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
    bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
    bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split

    # toggle tiling / floating
    bindsym $mod+Shift+space floating toggle

    # change focus between tiling / floating windows
    bindsym $mod+space focus mode_toggle

    # focus the parent container
    bindsym $mod+a focus parent

    # focus the child container
    #bindsym $mod+d focus child

    # switch to workspace
    bindsym $mod+1 workspace 1
    bindsym $mod+2 workspace 2
    bindsym $mod+3 workspace 3
    bindsym $mod+4 workspace 4
    bindsym $mod+5 workspace 5
    bindsym $mod+6 workspace 6
    bindsym $mod+7 workspace 7
    bindsym $mod+8 workspace 8
    bindsym $mod+9 workspace 9
    bindsym $mod+0 workspace 10

    # move focused container to workspace
    bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace 1
    bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace 2
    bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace 3
    bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace 4
    bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace 5
    bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace 6
    bindsym $mod+Shift+7 move container to workspace 7
    bindsym $mod+Shift+8 move container to workspace 8
    bindsym $mod+Shift+9 move container to workspace 9
    bindsym $mod+Shift+0 move container to workspace 10

    # reload the configuration file
    bindsym $mod+Shift+c reload
    # restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
    bindsym $mod+Shift+r restart
    # exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
    bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit         shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -b 'Yes, exit i3'         'i3-msg exit'"

    # resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
    mode "resize" {
            # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

            # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
            # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
            # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
            # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
            bindsym j resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym k resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym l resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym semicolon resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

            # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
            bindsym Left resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Down resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Up resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
            bindsym Right resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

            # back to normal: Enter or Escape
            bindsym Return mode "default"
            bindsym Escape mode "default"
    }

    bindsym $mod+r mode "resize"

    hide_edge_borders both


    for_window [title="urxvt"] border none
    for_window [class="Firefox"] border none
    for_window [class="Chromium"] border none

    # Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
    # finds out, if available)
    bar {
        status_command conky
        i3bar_command i3bar -t
        colors {
            background #060E0B
        }
        position top
    }
```

Comment: How does you `~/.conkyrc` looks like, notably the part after `TEXT`?

Comment: Added .conkyrc file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config you posted will not work without comma (`,`) at the end.

```
use_xft yes           
xftfont Terminus Regular:size=8
out_to_console yes
out_to_x no
double_buffer yes
update_interval 1.0
cpu_avg_samples 8
TEXT
[
{ "full_text" : " A: ${moc_album} Artist: ${moc_artist} Song:{moc_song} || ♬ : ${exec ~/bin/volume} " , "color" : "\#6599F6"},
{ "full_text" : "Total Down: ${totaldown eth0} "  },
{ "full_text" : "Total Up: ${totalup eth0} " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
{ "full_text" : "GPU Temp: ${exec nvidia-smi -q -d TEMPERATURE | grep 'GPU Current Temp' | cut -c39-40}°C " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
{ "full_text" : "CPU: $cpu% " , "color" : "\#20B00B" },
{ "full_text" : "RAM: $mem/$memmax " , "color" : "\#ffffff" },
{ "full_text" : " ${time %a %d/%b %R}"},
{ "full_text" : " ${exec skb 1}" , "color" : "\#42BC24" }
],
```

And I changed CPU color also. Now it looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Problem was in bypassing [Wrapper script](https://i3wm.org/docs/user-contributed/conky-i3bar.html)

Comment: Very well observed, I completely missed that and started testing based on my own config (which contains a comma)

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://s9.postimg.org/41pzua52n/Oct_24_2016_00_16_05_Cut.png

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://s9.postimg.org/41pzua52n/Oct_24_2016_00_16_05_Cut.png)

Comment: Thank you for help, but when I copied Your conf file to my .conf/conky/conky.conf, I get something like [this](https://s9.postimg.org/41pzua52n/Oct_24_2016_00_16_05_Cut.png),
I think its happens because i have new version of conky 
`code` gyokY570L% conky -v
conky 1.10.5_pre compiled Sat Oct  8 06:45:53 UTC 2016 for Linux 4.7.6-1-ARCH x86_64
`code`
now I try to make this conf file , tag ${color B00B0B} not shows as you see, but color not changes too, I think its not conky problem, but i3 conf file, because I can change color of full statusline in i3/conf

Comment: `code conky.config = {
    background = false, 
    double_buffer = true, 
    out_to_x = false,
    out_to_console = true,
    update_interval = 2.0,
    total_run_times = 0,
    use_spacer = 'none',
    own_window = false,
    imlib_cache_size = 0,
};

conky.text = [[
 ${color B00B0B}${top name 1 color B00B0B}${color B00B0}
]];
`

Comment: @gyok can you update your question and post your `i3 conf` file, please?

Comment: added, can you give me your config file?

Comment: My config will not help you, since I am using `i3blocks` instead of `conky`. But I reproduced your problem again, and it seems that you trying to run `conky` directly, bypassing the [Wrapper script](https://i3wm.org/docs/user-contributed/conky-i3bar.html)

Comment: @gyok also, `i3bar_command i3bar -t` can cause conflicts too. But first you need to follow manual and run conky with [Wrapper script](https://i3wm.org/docs/user-contributed/conky-i3bar.html)

Comment: Thank you wery much, the proble was in escaping wrapper script, i not anderstand before how i3bar really works

Comment: @gyok, you're welcome. I will update answer then with this link.